# Data permissions Docker for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, permissions, owncloud

I'm using Docker for Windows, with owncloud container, and I shared volumes, setting up on docker-compose.yml, in order to persist the data.
Extract from my docker-compose.yml

` owncloud:

```
image: jobel/owncloud:1.1

links: 

    - db:db

ports:

    - 8002:80   

volumes:

    - f:/Program Files/Docker/Docker VM/owncloudconfig:/var/www/html

    - f:/Program Files/Docker/Docker VM/owncloudconfig/apps:/var/www/html/apps

    - f:/Program Files/Docker/Docker VM/owncloudconfig/config:/var/www/html/config

    - f:/Program Files/Docker/Docker VM/owncloudconfig/data:/var/www/html/data
```

`

Data are present but when I try to connect on my web browser, it says : "Your data folder can be read by other users. Please change the directory permissions in 0770 mode so that the content is not listed by other users." (translate fr->eng)

But how can I change the windows folder permissions to 0770 ? ;(

Or what are the others solutions?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Windows client, you can configure the docker to allow read/write on specific drives. In your case, it is the `F:` drive. This should fix your permissions problem.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The web-server running in Docker is checking the folder permissions, which is nothing to do with windows; you need to verify the folder permissions inside Docker itself

Below is an example which you can play with, you just need to let docker execute the Linux command in a container

hope this helps

eg:

$ docker container exec -t local-container **ls -ld /var/www/html/config**

$ docker container exec -t local-container **chmod 0770 /var/www/html/config**